# SSIS- date error when loading from flatfile source to OLEDB destination

Tags: sql, types, ssis, date-format, date-conversion

I'm fairly new to SSIS and my ingestion package is giving me a hard time :(

I have a .csv file with a column date with data as "2019/11/03". ("yyyy/mm/dd")within quotes
I have defined this as a DT_DBDATE in flat file connection manager
My SQL database table has a column with datatype as datetime.

While trying to ingest data into the table using SSIS, my table gets loaded with system date. i.e, the date when I'm running this package. I also tried DT_DATE and still received todays date in my table. It is so weird and I just cant seem to understand what the issue is.

I changed the datatype of the SQL table column from datetime to String and SSIS to DT_STR. Tried ingesting again and ended up getting 00:00 in the table. Not sure what is happening :(

Please help!!

Comment: Is the sample date listed in March or November?

Comment: Its November. Thanks, I missed to mention that. Have edited the post